# invert and merge an array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I would like to invert an array of objects, and merge them.

`before = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}]`

expected result:

`after = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'a', 4: 'b'}`

How would you do this? With underscore/lodash?

Answer (score 2):

With lodash, if you use chaining, you can make it a lot more readable.

```
var before = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}];
var after = _(before)
  .map(_.invert)
  .reduce(_.merge);
console.log(after);
// Object {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "a", 4: "b"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var before = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}];
var after = {};

before.forEach(function(e) {
    Object.keys(e).forEach(function(k) {
        after[e[k]] = k;
    });
});

console.log(after);//{ '1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'a', '4': 'b' }
```

Answer (score 0):

With underscore/lodash:

`_.extend.apply(this,_.map(data,_.invert))`